# Install openerp 7 on windows azure platform

Tags: azure, ubuntu-12.04, openerp-7

**I want to install openerp on windows azure platform**. 
*Firstly, i think install a virtual machine on windows azure, after that, i think install ubuntu 12.04 LTS. And finally, i will install openerp 7.*
 **Is It the best way to run openerp 7 on windows azure ?  Which has already installed openerp 7 on microsoft windows azure platform?
How should I proceed?**
Please, give me your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You should have use all in one installer 
or you can also install it on virtual machine